# How to find if my traffic is HTTP or TCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, https, google-cloud-network-load-balancer

Hi I am trying to learn different LB options in Google Cloud Platform. I came across different options like suggesting to use HTTP(s) for Http traffic and TCP/SSL proxy for TCP traffic. But I am not able to differentiate between HTTP traffic and TCP traffic. By seeing an application how can I find out does it require http/TCP load balancer?

This Question may look very basic to experts out there, but It will helpful for me if you can explain in simple terms.

Answer (score 1):

**HTTP(S) Load Balancing** is a proxy-based L7 load balancer that enables to run and scale services worldwide by using a external IP address or it enables you to run and scale your services by using an internal IP address based on the type of HTTP(S) Load Balancing.

There are 2 types HTTP(s) load balancing are available :

1. Internal HTTP(S) Load Balancing
2. External HTTP(S) Load Balancing

Internal HTTP(S) Load Balancing distributes HTTP and HTTPS traffic to backends hosted on GCP instances via internal IP address.

External HTTP(S) Load Balancing distributes HTTP and HTTPS traffic to backends hosted on GCP instances via External IP address.

**TCP Proxy Load Balancing** is a reverse proxy L4 load balancer that distributes TCP traffic coming from the internet to virtual machine (VM) instances.
When using TCP Proxy Load Balancing, traffic coming over a TCP connection is terminated at the load balancing layer, and then forwarded to the closest available backend using TCP or SSL.

Kindly refer below link to understand more about choosing load balancing for Google cloud platform

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/choosing-load-balancer